# Can I put a second layer of caulk over newly installed caulk to fill a gap?

Tags: caulking

My bathroom backsplash-to-wall junction was just re-caulked yesterday. (The old caulk was discolored and showing signs of mold.) But on one side of the countertop where there's a 3/8" gap between wall and backsplash, the new caulk was applied at a slightly lower level than the top of the backsplash, meaning there's a small area where water will pool on top of the caulk instead of draining back down onto the backsplash and countertop.

Question: can I just add more caulk on top of the now-dried other caulk, in order to raise the caulk level above the backsplash top so water will drain correctly? Or do I need to rip out all the caulk and start from scratch?

I'm using [GE Max 5000](http://www.acehardware.com/product/index.jsp?productId=1425862&CAWELAID=109369733&cagpspn=pla) caulk if it matters.

Comment: give it 24 hours before touching up any little gaps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally it would be one continuous bead of caulking, however for 3/8" of a gap at the very top, you will probably be OK just adding a bit more caulking to fill it in.  However, if you don't want to have to touch it again for a while--and considering the low cost and relative ease of applying it--I think I would be inclined to remove the existing bead and apply a new one that covers the entire length. That way you don't have to worry about water getting behind it.